# Is there any way we can skip the account which is raising exception i.e. duplicate entry of that account and other account get inserted in oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, error-handling, unique, sql-insert

Suppose we have a table which consist number of records for the user accounts. Now we are running a procedure which is picking accounts from 1 system to source i.e. oracle. We have added constraints to the table in oracle for ID  which should be unique. In that procedure we have added an exception which will throw the error when unique constraint is violated everytime and procedure will fail.
Now my question is- Is there any way procedure can skip that account which is already present in the source table which is causing exception and rest insert go fine and procedure will be completed successfully?

I try to raise the exception but procedure is getting failed after raising the exception for unique key constraint error.

Comment: Whenever you have a question, please post a little sample data (CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for all tables involved, relevant columns only) so the people who want to help you can recreate the problem and test their ideas. Also post the exact results you want from that data, and explain why you want those results from that data. Lastly, don't post any images as they cant be cut and pasted.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't explain how exactly you're doing it, so I'll presume it is some kind of a cursor FOR loop which fetches user accounts from source table and inserts them into a target table.

Use *inner* (within the loop) `begin-exception-end` block which will handle exception (basically, you'll just ignore it) and proceed with another user account.

Something like this:

```
begin
  for cur_r in (select user_account, ... from source_table) loop
  
    -- start inner BEGIN-EXCEPTION-END block
    begin
      insert into target_table (...) values (cur_r.user_account, ...);
    
    -- handle exception
    exception
      when dup_val_on_index then
        -- ignore it
        null;
    end;
    -- end innser BEGIN-EXCEPTION-END block
  end loop;
end;
```

---

On the other hand, can't you avoid duplicates in query?

```
for cur_r in (select user_account, ...
              from source_table s
              where not exists (select null
                                from target_table t
                                where t.user_account = s.user_account
                               )
             ) loop
```

---

**[EDIT]** You commented that you're either updating or inserting values - that's actually what `merge` (also known as *upsert*) does:

```
merge into target_table a
  using source_table b
  on (a.user_account = b.user_account)
when matched then update set
  a.name = b.name,
  a.address = b.address
when not matched then insert (user_account, name, address)
  values (b.user_accout, b.name, b.address);
```

Comment: No we cant avoid duplicates in the query because we are either updating or inserting the accounts in the source table.

Comment: That's what MERGE does. See sample code in edited answer; might provide an easy way out of your problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use DBMS_ERRLOG package to create a table where the errors will be logged, there is an example in LiveSQL: https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_JNEICX6W0LNOA88CQIXO9A22A.html and discussion in AskTom https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=error-logging-using-log-errors-into